# separate handlers lvalue and rvalue [] operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is there a way to make the [] operator to be handled differently in lvalue and rvalue contexts?

Example code:

```
include <stdio.h>

class test {
public:
  unsigned a;
  unsigned const & operator [](unsigned const idx) const;
  unsigned & operator [](unsigned const idx);
};

unsigned const & test::operator [](unsigned const idx) const {
  printf("const [%u] called\n", idx);
  return a;
}

unsigned & test::operator [](unsigned const idx) {
  printf("non-const [%u] called\n", idx);
  return a;
}

int main() {
  test t;
  unsigned a;
  a = 0;
  printf("a = %u\n", a);
  t[0] = a;
  printf("stored a to t[0]; a = %u\n", a);
  a = t[0];
  printf("read a from t[0]; a = %u\n", a);
}
```

`t[0] = a;` has lvalue-context [] operator and `a = t[0];` has rvalue-context [] operator, but they both are handled via non-const function. I tried also to declare `unsigned const & test::operator [](unsigned const idx)` method but it not compiles and say that such overloading is not allowed. Is there a way (i need it) to handle [] operator via different handlers for `t[0]=a;` and `a=t[0];` ?

Please don't mark this as duplicate of [C++ Operator Overloading [ ] for lvalue and rvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051502/c-operator-overloading-for-lvalue-and-rvalue) because this question is not the same, even if it looks like similarly.

Added simplified code that may be also related:
    include

```
class test {
public:
  unsigned a;
  unsigned const & operator [](unsigned const idx) const;
  /*unsigned & operator [](unsigned const idx);*/
};

unsigned const & test::operator [](unsigned const idx) const {
  printf("const [%u] called\n", idx);
  return a;
}

/*unsigned & test::operator [](unsigned const idx) {
  printf("non-const [%u] called\n", idx);
  return a;
}*/

int main() {
  test t;
  unsigned a;
  a = t[0];
  printf("read a from t[0]; a = %u\n", a);
}
```

I commented out non-const operator [], removed writing to t[0], and now it compiles and uses needed method for []. But once i uncomment non-const one it starts using it and ignores previous one. And the question, in another words: is there a way to make const one preferred over non-const one in all places where it is possible?

Comment: Read up on [ref-qualified functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions) cppref link might not be the best resource, actually

Comment: In both cases `t` is surely an lvalue. You appear to be asking about differentiating between read and write access to `t`. In which case you probably want to use a proxy - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806786/distinguish-between-read-and-write-using-operator-overloading-in-c

Comment: In C++, "lvalue" and "rvalue" don't really mean the more traditional "left-hand side of assignment" and "right-hand side of assignment".

Comment: Unfortunately, ref-qualified function didn't helped - it still uses lvalue one for both cases if it exists. As for proxy class - i know it possible, but it looks like too many coding for such a simple problem :(. And yes, it is read vs write access to `t`, but from compilers point of view it should be read-only vs read-write access to the value returned by `[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No and yes.

No, context cannot change the return type of an operator or function in C++.

Yes, you can fake it using a pseudo reference.

A pseudo reference is an object that overloads `operator =(T const&)&&` and `operator T()&&`.

```
struct pr_unsigned { // lazy name, do better
  unsigned* target;
  void operator=(unsigned const& in)&&{ *target=in; }
  operator unsigned()&&{ return *target; }
  pr_unsigned(pr_unsigned&&)=delete;
};
```

this is a bit of a toy, but:

```
pr_unsigned test::operator [](unsigned const idx) { return {&a}; }
```

we now have different code paths for `test[2]=3;` and `foo=test[0];`.

This is far from a perfect emulation; `auto x = test[2];` does the wrong thing.  But it isn't horrid.

You could store a `test*` and `unsigned idx` in `pr_unsigned` and have arbitrary code run on `test` when elements are assigned to/from.